# Eclipse – ASP classic plugin

Tags: eclipse, asp-classic, eclipse-plugin

Where can I find an Eclipse plugin for ASP classic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a plug-in called EclipseColorer that provides Syntax Highligting. You can find the plugin at http://colorer.sourceforge.net/ You won't get the outline feature and it's a little buggy but it works pretty well for the most part.

Comment: I've started using it today and I really like it.  Sometimes, you have to edit some text in the file for the syntax highlighter to fully kick in.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: I've been using the colorer for about 2 months. It's better than nothing, but the lack of functional matching pairs and code suggest make it less than ideal. I guess I'm going to have to settle for Visual Studio. If anyone comes across a better ASP plugin for Eclipse, please comment!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think one exists.  I know when I was stuck doing Classic I searched far and wide for a plugin or editor, and apart from Visual Studio which has rudimentary syntax highlighting, there wasn't anything I found.  I just use Notepad++